# apt-get Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Trying to run **any** apt-get commands from the terminal gives me a syntax error. Synaptic and Software Center work fine (Ubuntu 13.04).

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install mpack
 /usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

I was installing icedtea-7 java browser plugin for online banking around the time the error started but not sure if related. Any ideas?

Thanks

**Updated**: All other sudo commands seem fine.

Contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner
# deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free # disabled on upgrade to raring
```

Comment: Could you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? Can you run other `sudo` commands OK?

Comment: Other sudo commands run ok. I posted sources.list, thanks

Comment: Well, your sources seem OK. Could you also post the output of these commands: `which apt-get`, `file $(which apt-get)` and `ls -l $(which apt-get)`?

Answer (score -1):

A good start for fixing apt problems is usually cleaning the cache and updating the indices:
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get update

If the problem persists, some of the list files might be corrupted. Removing them manually and then updating the indices works around that problem.

Comment: Any "sudo apt-get" command gives the same error

Comment: Has the apt-get command maybe been overwritten? What does "$ which apt-get" show? Should be /usr/bin/apt-get. What is the output of "$ ls -lh /usr/bin/apt-get" ? The size should be around 187k.

Comment: "which apt-get" does show /usr/bin/apt-get and the file is 190.9kB