# Replace/reinstall /usr/bin/apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Running any sudo apt-get command gives the error:

```
/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

(see [Related question](https://superuser.com/questions/595769/apt-get-syntax-error-end-of-file-unexpected))

Is there a way to reinstall the `apt-get` program or replace the file `/usr/bin/apt-get` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apt-get Syntax error: end of file unexpected](http://superuser.com/questions/595769/apt-get-syntax-error-end-of-file-unexpected)

Comment: Admittedly that is a duplicate but considering it did not receive a working solution I am inclined to leave this question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: The output shown is taken from a debian system, as I don't have access to a ubuntu machine. Ubuntu should be sufficient similar.

`apt-get` is an *Advanced front-end for dpkg* (according to its description), so you should still be able to you `dpkg`. First, determine your `apt` version:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep apt | head -n 1
ii  apt                                         0.8.10.3                       Advanced front-end for dpkg
```

Grab the appropriate `deb` package from `[http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/][1]`
(I took the link from the [linked question](https://superuser.com/q/595769/195224) -- I'm absolutely not sure, if this is the right repository for your ubuntu version!).

Then you can try to remove `apt` from your system

```
$ dpkg -r apt
```

and reinstall it:

```
$ dpkg -i apt_[...].deb
```

`dpkg -r` does not touch the *conffiles*, so if that does not work, you can try to use `dpkg -P apt`, which does a purge and removes also the *conffiles* (from `man dpkg`: *Conffiles are configuration files that are listed in the `DEBIAN/conffiles` control file*)

Comment: Thanks. I get dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of apt:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on apt.
 unattended-upgrades depends on apt.
 ubuntu-extras-keyring depends on apt.

Comment: @user224461: You can force the removal with `dpkg --force-all -r apt`. But please _double-check_ that you have the correct deb package of `apt` at hand!

Comment: Ok thanks. How do I know which of the apt packages I need? (32-bit ubuntu 13.04) I have apt 0.9.7.7 apt_0.9.7.7ubuntu5_i386.deb? apt_0.9.7.7ubuntu4_i386.deb? or apt_0.9.7.5ubuntu5_i386.deb? apt_0.9.7.5ubuntu5.5_i386.deb..

Comment: Since you have apt 0.9.7.7 it is one of the apt_0.9.7.7 packages. But I don't know what's the difference between the ubuntu4 and ubuntu5 suffix, as I don't use Ubuntu myself, sorry.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked by "sudo dpkg --force-all -r apt" then i tried "dpkg -i apt_[...].deb" with the ubuntu5 version of the .deb file but got an error removed again and reran with the ubuntu4